# How can I Migrate Wordpress off of Google App Engine

Tags: php, wordpress, google-app-engine

There are dozens of articles for migrating a Wordpress install TO Google App Engine, but I can't find any to migrate it FROM GAE to something like WPEngine.

I'd simply love to UpdraftPlus to do it, but I can't create a backup because the filesystem is not writeable in GAE.

I could simply use a copy of the database dump and my local version of the filesystem, but that loses all the remote uploaded images that I created.

Also, I don't really know how to "undo" many of the GAE configurations that have to do with the filesystem, uploads, database connectivity, etc.  If I change the 
db credentials and deactivate the GAE plugin, will my site just work?

Thanks!
Lou

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else experiencing the same issue, I did the following and it was really quite simple:

1. uploaded the wp-content folder from the source GAE folders (on my local machine) to the new host
2. used the native 'export' feature in the Wordpress admin: /wp-admin/export.php
3. used the import feature in the Wordpress admin (you do have to install a plugin): /wp-admin/import.php
4. Went through and activated my theme and my plugins
5. Updated all my settings on all my pages

Then I had to edit my function.php and header.php files as they included a few hardcoded references to IDs (posts, pages, categories).

After that, it was done!

Comment: It's worth noting that when I tried doing an import of the database from GAE, everything got all messy.  The export/import was by far more successful.